# Internal Compile Error in NSIS

Tags: nsis

I am creating a NSIS installer which installs multiple .exe's as well. Now these other .exe's makes the installer bigger than 2GB which is the set limit. I used [WinImage](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/WimImage_plug-in) PlugIn which is supposed to remove the limit. I replaced the files in my NSIS folder with these of the PlugIn's but i still receive the same error. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Including some example code is always helpful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are still hitting the compiler limitation then something in your install script is still including large file(s) directly into your .exe.

To use the WinImage plug-in you first must compile a installer that just builds the .wim file locally on your machine. Then you must remove the `File`/`File /r` commands from your installer and replace them with calls to the WinImage plug-in.

Comment: Thank you very much. Have been struggling the entire day with this error never noticed i still had large files being added.

Comment: sorry for asking you this after such a long time but the script consists of File /oname=$PLUGINSDIR\Setup_Name "Setup_Path". If i replace them with the WinImage would that do the trick?

Comment: You only have to replace the really large files.